# How do I check if input field is either correct/incorrect/incomplete in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several forms and each form has about 50+ input fields. 
Each input field has it's own validation checks. For example.

```
<div>
    <label>Birth Weight : </label>
    <div>
        <span class="addingUnits unitsGrams">
            <input id="birthWeightInGrams" class="form-control" onchange="validateBirthweight()" type="search" placeholder="eg. 1500" maxlength="4">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this validation :

```
function validateBirthweight(){
    var weight = document.getElementById('birthWeightInGrams').value;
    if(weight.length==0){
        toastr.error('Birth Weight - Value cannot be empty');
        $('#birthWeightInGrams').addClass('addRed')
        $('#birthWeightInGrams').removeClass('addGreen')
    }
    else if(isNaN(weight)){
            toastr.error('Birth Weight - Numbers only');
            $('#birthWeightInGrams').addClass('addRed')
            $('#birthWeightInGrams').removeClass('addGreen')
        }
    else if(weight>=1501 && weight<=5000){ 
            $('#birthWeightInGrams').removeClass('addRed')
            $('#birthWeightInGrams').addClass('addGreen')
        }
}
```

I am then applying a event listener to each of the input fields:

```
function InputsPatientForm(e){
    var inputsAllSelected = 0;
    $('#firstPanelID input[type=search]:visible:enabled').each(function(i) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("addGreen") && !$(this).hasClass("addRed")){
           inputsAllSelected += 0;
           }
        else if($(this).hasClass("addGreen"))
            {
                 inputsAllSelected += 1;
            }
        else if($(this).hasClass("addRed")){
                 inputsAllSelected -= 1;
                }
    });
    return (inputsAllSelected)
}
```

I need to know if **any** field is incorrect then I return red(if they contain he class "addRed". Then if any is incomplete then return orange(if it has neither "addRed" or "addGreen". If ALL is complete (all contains "hasGreen") then return green. 
**EDIT**

What is a better way to check for all this besides using these add and removing classes.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? I'm going to assume it isn't changing to green/red? If so have you used inspect element to see if the class has been added or used `console.log()` for debugging things?

Comment: Hi - Sorry I wasn't clear. Yes I have been checking using that. I actually just wanted to know if there is a better way to check if these classes are either complete/incorrect/incomplete as adding and removing these classes seem very inefficient.

Comment: Well you could bind an event listener to all elements with a class and use `$(this)` to check that input. This way you will have one function to deal with all those elements and it will only trigger upon the clients input and will only check that element so no need to loop through each one....

Answer (score 0):

I'm being silly. I feel like this is still a decent validation check. 
So I created 2 variables.

- One is for checking whether or not it is complete or incomplete.
- One is for checking whether or not there is an error.

Checks as follows:

```
function InputsPatientForm(e){
        var completeIncompleteCounter = 0;
        var errorCounter = 0;
        $('#firstPanelID input[type=search]:visible:enabled').each(function(i) {
            if(!$(this).hasClass("addGreen") && !$(this).hasClass("addRed")){
               completeIncompleteCounter += 0;
               }
            else if($(this).hasClass("addGreen"))
                {
                     completeIncompleteCounter += 1;
                }
            else if($(this).hasClass("addRed")){
                     errorCounter += 1;
                    }
        });
        return [completeIncompleteCounter,errorCounter];
    }
```